# GAE: editing existing object with django forms: how to check on instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, django-forms, instance

I don't really get the data flow of editing an existing object in GAE with django forms. The user clicks a link `<li><a id="entry" href="edit/{{ entry.title|urlencode }}">edit</a></li>`. With the `title` information I create an instance of the object and fill the form with the data. How do I retrieve the instance from the returning data (in a given view)? Do I have to pass it back and forth!?

```
class EditEntry(webapp.RequestHandler):

def get(self, entry_title):
    entry_title = urllib.unquote(entry_title.encode('ascii')).decode('utf-8')

    entry_get = Entry.all().filter("title =", entry_title).get()
    cats = db.Query(Category)
    e_form = EntryForm(instance=entry_get)        
    template_values = {
        'entry_get':entry_get,                           
        'cats':cats,
        'e_form': e_form,
        }    
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'editor.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone ever should wonder. In my case you do have to pass the instance identifier back and forth. More precisely, the key which can be converted as strings.

> To convert a string-encoded key back to a Key object, the application passes the string to the Key constructor.

```
entry_get = Entry.all().filter("title =", entry_title).get()
```

To pass it to your template you can either use the key constructor directly:

```
template_values = {
'entry_get':entry_get.key(),
...
```

Or like a ordinary object

```
template_values = {
'entry_get':entry_get,
...
```

If you go for the second option you can retrieve the key in your template using the template language filter `{{ entry_get.key }}`. Creating an URL using the key:

```
<form action="/new/{{ entry_get }}" method="post">
...
```

And using the `key` constructor to convert back to a key object:

```
def post(self, key_name):
    key_name = urllib.unquote(key_name.encode('ascii')).decode('utf-8')
    entry_obj = db.get(db.Key(key_name))
    ...
```